# Java owlapi extract

Tags: java, rdf, owl-api, object-property

I have an ontology

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000050">
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000051"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#TransitiveProperty"/>
    <oboInOwl:hasDbXref rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">BFO:0000050</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
    <oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">external</oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace>
    <oboInOwl:id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">part_of</oboInOwl:id>
    <oboInOwl:shorthand rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">part_of</oboInOwl:shorthand>
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">part of</rdfs:label>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

I'm trying to extract all the ObjectProperties,

```
for (OWLObjectProperty obp : ont.getObjectPropertiesInSignature()){
    System.out.println(obp.toString());
}
```

this will print the name of ObjectProperty, e.g. http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000050.

I wonder how to get the rdfs:label, e.g. part of

Answer (score 1):

The `rdfs:label` in OWL is an [annotation](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#Annotations).
To get the `label` you must query for the annotation of the objectProperty you want.

To display all annotations of an ontology you can do something like that :

```
final OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(my_file));

final List<OWLAnnotation> annotations = ontology.objectPropertiesInSignature()//
    .filter(objectProperty -> objectProperty.equals(the_object_property_I_want))//
    .flatMap(objectProperty -> ontology.annotationAssertionAxioms(objectProperty.getIRI()))//
    .map(OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom::getAnnotation)//
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (final OWLAnnotation annotation : annotations)
    System.out.println(annotation.getProperty() + "\t" + annotation.getValue());
```

`getObjectPropertiesInSignature()` is deprecated in the modern (more than one year) version of owlapi (5). So please considere using the `stream` version `objectPropertiesInSignature` of [java-8](http://www.java8.org/) . [java-9](http://www.baeldung.com/new-java-9) have been release few days ago, so it is a good time to learn the `stream` functionnality.

NB: the annotations are almost free, but [OWL2](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Annotation_Properties) have put some more standardisation on it, so there is annotations with 'predefined semantics'.

Comment: This is a great solution. I am new to this and other classes depends heavy on owlapi 4.3. Are there any chance you can create a 4.3 version of this solution?

Comment: for (final OWLObjectProperty oprop : ontology.getObjectPropertiesInSignature()) for (final OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom axiom : ontology.getAnnotationAssertionAxioms(oprop.getIRI()))   System.out.println(oprop + "\t" + axiom.getAnnotation().getValue());  Sorry, I vomit doing this with old-versions.

Comment: Sorry mate, I put your example in, I got, 'code' <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/BFO_0000050> uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLLiteralImplString@9da10122, Could you help me to solve this?

Comment: Well, I give you a very good answer. Then you validate it and ask more help. I give it to you and then you unvalidate the answer... So, no, I will not help you solve your problem without a complete proof of work from you, include full ontology and full code of your trys with dependencies. One could have ask it from the very beginning.